# Play audio file from string in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, variables, client, html5-audio

I have the contents of an mp3 file saved as a variable, (this isn't meant to be practical, just for a little project of mine), and I wish to play the contents of this variable as an audio file. This would be a simple task with something like node, but unfortunately I must do this entirely client side.

Please note I can not just save the content of the string as an mp3 file, I need to be able to play it from a variable.

I have looked into this, but from what I have found, it appears that this can not be done. If any of you have a solution, I would appreciate hearing it.

Comment: What sort of encoding?

Comment: .mp3 files are complex encoded binary files, how exactly does one store that as a string in javascript? Anything can be done with enough time, but if you really have .mp3 as a string, you would probably have to read the specifications for the MP3 format, figure out how to get the header and the billions of frames that make up a compressed audio file like that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**This is not very practical**, as you're going to get very high memory footprints within the JS engine and will likely cause unnecessary garbage collection... but it is possible to a base64 encode the MP3 which can then be fed into the `src` attribute of an `<audio>` tag.

Because it is unrealistically to provide a base64 encoded MP3 in an answer here I'll provide a Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/4t6bg95z/1/

But the gist of the code can be something like:

```
var audio = document.getElementById('audio');
audio.src = "data:audio/mp3;base64,..."; //This is a base64 encoded string of an MP3 file

window.beep = function() {
    audio.play();
}
```

Obviously, it is much better practice to provide a URL to the audio source instead, as that's the intended usage of the Audio API.

Comment: If possible I'd suggest using Blobs & Object URLs instead. Blobs are intended to handle binary data and will be a bit more memory efficient in the JS engine, especially when passing the value around functions, where blobs are passed by reference unlike strings, which are passed by value. Object URLs can be created from blobs to to be used in `src` attributes